# How to call external function using pointer?

Tags: c++

My plugin is called from a host application. This host application sends some function address to my plugin, and plugin needs to execute this external function.

Host application is written in Delphi and my plugin is written in C++ Borland Builder.

Plugin initialization procedure is called **PLUGIN_INIT**, and it is called by host application.

External function address is supplied as the 6th element of **params** array. This function has one input char* parameter and it returns void* pointer. So, all code looks like this:

```
typedef void *(*F)(char *); // external function type

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool WINAPI PLUGIN_INIT(int *params) {

   F func = (F)*(params + 5); // here I get function address
   try {

      void *retValue = func("input_value"); // trying to call external function
   } catch (...) {

      printf("error");
   }
}
```

As the result, I always get "error" message. What can be the problem? Other plugins, written in Delphi and using similar declarations, work fine.

**EDIT:**

Inspecting in debugger shows that **func** function pointer points to memory filled with zeroes.

Comment: Maybe you should catch for a specific exception type so you can get the details of the error?

Comment: Yes, 6th - it's not a problem here

Comment: An error in your crazy pointer shenanigans would not throw an exception. If it throws an exception, then this part is working (or at least appears to work).

Comment: @OldProgrammer using "catch (std::exception &e)" does not intercept exception at all.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your print statement and examine the program state when the error is being handled in the exception handler.

Comment: @pasztorpisti this code is compiled as a DLL, and later it is loaded by a host app. I don't know how it can be debugged when it is executed by the host app.

Comment: Sure it can.  Most IDEs will allow you to debug the dll and either launch the exe to debug under, or attach to a process.

Comment: As OldProgrammer said. In the c++ debugger you just open the DLL project, set up the command that launches the host app, and you are ready to go. Set breakpoints in the source code and launch/start debugging. If your DLL project is in Visual Studio then this will be childs play. The same is true for C++ Builder.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Anyway there is not much to observe here. Function "func" gets some address. But it fails to execute. Another plugins (written in Delphi) using the same workflow execute normally.

Comment: With a debugger you can execute that simple plugin init function step by step and see where it fails instead of printing in an exception handler where the callstack has already been unwound (making important information lost).

Comment: @pasztorpisti Yes, I launched it in debugging mode - it just throws "Access violation at address ..." when trying to execute external function.

Comment: @Kibernetik Thats already more info than what you had with printf. Now comes the part where you have to put a breakpoint to the beginning of plugin init and you execute it step by step with the "step into" and "step over" functions of the debugger. At each step you will be able to check the value of the memory and the variables. It may be boring, but this is unfortunately part of software development. :-D Fortunately with higher level languages these kind of errors (access violation) happen rarely...

Comment: @pasztorpisti Yes, here I have only 1 variable - function "func". It gets some value (memory address), but throws exception when trying to run it in next code line. What else should I inspect here in the debugger?

Comment: @Kibernetik For example you can try debugging the host app from delphi and check whether the first line of the func is reached when the plugin tries to call it. If it doesn't reach the first line of func then probably something else is wrong. Wrong function pointer, wrong calling convention, whatever, the magic and curse of low level programming. Sometimes you have to switch to assembly view and step the code instruction-by-instruction to see what goes wrong but that is rare. Use your imagination. Debugging is often about excluding possible locations of the error until it becomes very small.

Comment: @pasztorpisti Host application is not available for debugging - it is just an EXE file from some vendor.

Comment: What is the calling convention of the function you are expected to call from the plugin?

Comment: @pasztorpisti I tried all possible calling conventions in compiler

Comment: If `func` points to memory filled with zeros then it is probaby not actually a valid function pointer ...